# Undefined while pushing OBJ in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm trying to create items in canvas for a website that i'm creating. 
While using an Object and Array push I used an Alert to indicate me what's in the Array but it tells me that it's undefined. 
Any suggestion on how I can fix that or did I do something wrong in my JS.
Thank you

```
function products(tag, name, price, src, description){
    this.Tag = tag;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Price = price;
    this.Src = src;
    this.Description = description;
}

var product = [];

product.push = new products(tag,"name", price, "path/to/my/item", "description");
```

When I do this with all my real informations and I do a **"alert(product[0].name)"** it doesn't show me the name it gives me an **"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error** and when I do a **"alert(product[0])"** theres an alert but it tells me **"Undefined"**.

Comment: You are overwriting the push method of Array.prototype. You have to call push like a function: product.push(new Products());

Comment: if your query was solved please accept the answer that was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to the following, you are assigning your product to [.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

> The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

```
product.push(new products(tag,"name", price, "path/to/my/item", "description"));
```

When you use

```
product.push = new products(tag,"name", price, "path/to/my/item", "description");
```

`push` becomes the property of `product`

[image]

```js
 function products(tag, name, price, src, description){
        this.Tag = tag;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
        this.Src = src;
        this.Description = description;
    }

    var product = [];

    product.push(new products('just a tag',"Kevin", 'price', "path/to/my/item", "description"));
    alert(product[0].Name)
```

Comment: still undefined when I alert the name of my first product of the Array

Comment: how did you alert this?

Comment: @Kevin see my updated answer, your name start with uppercase `N` use `product[0].Name`

Comment: It is working for me now, but one last question is it normal that it gives me "[object Object]" when I alert product ?

Comment: @Kevin yes it is, try `console.log(product);` please don't forget to accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

`push` is a function, so you need to call it with parens `push()`. You are trying to use `=`, so it will not work.

In your case, you should do:
`product.push( new products(tag,"name", price, "path/to/my/item", "description") );`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control

Answer (score 1):

First you should push like

```
function products(tag, name, price, src, description){
this.Tag = tag;
this.Name = name;
this.Price = price;
this.Src = src;
this.Description = description;
}

var product = [];

product.push(new products("tag", "name", "price", "path/to/my/item", "description"));
```

and access the property like this `product[0]["Name"]`
for reference check this out [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Opps my bad, it works with this product[0].Name also, property name is case sensitive, so change it to "Name"